# Universal envoloping algebra of a free Lie algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

In [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra), the universal enveloping algebra of a free Lie algebra on a set X is defined to be the free associative algebra generated by X.

It is said that by the Poincaré–Birkhoff–Witt theorem the universal enveloping algebra of a free Lie algebra is isomorphic to the symmetric algebra of the free Lie algebra as a graded vector space (both sides are graded by giving elements of X degree 1).

By definition, the universal enveloping algebra of a free Lie algebra can be non-commutative. The symmetric algebra of a free Lie algebra is commutative.

Are there some references which prove that the universal enveloping algebra of a free Lie algebra is isomorphic to the symmetric algebra of the free Lie algebra as a graded vector space? Thank you very much.

Comment: Look up a proof of the PBW theorem; many texts on Lie theory will prove it. Then just apply it to this case.