# Difference between Free Lie algebra and universal enveloping algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

I have seen so many questions about free Lie algebra and universal enveloping algebra. As in this question ([Universal envoloping algebra of a free Lie algebra.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025518/universal-envoloping-algebra-of-a-free-lie-algebra)), a reader asked for the universal enveloping algebra of a free Lie algebra. I am following the book on Lie algebra written by Humphreys. In this book, he didn't give much about free Lie algebra and its construction. He said if $X$ is a set then to construct its free Lie algebra go through the vector space generated by X as a basis and consider this as a subalgebra of tensor algebra. I can not understand how to do this. Kindly explain this to me. There are so many questions on universal enveloping algebra on this site and I studied them but didn't get my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that an universal enveloping algebra is an associative algebra, wheras [Lie algebras are seldom associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287171/does-there-exist-a-non-trivial-associative-lie-algebra). So, it almost never happens that a universal enveloping algebra can also be a Lie algebra.

If $F$ is a set, the free Lie algebra on $F$ (over a field $k$) is basically a Lie algebra over $k$ which contains $F$ and which, besides that, satisfies the minimal possible amount of relations among its elements. So, for instance, if $F=\{X,Y\}$, then the free Lie algebra on $F$ contains $X$ and $Y$. It also contains $[X,Y]$ and $[Y,X]$ and, of course, $[X,Y]=-[Y,X]$, since this relation must hold for any Lie algebra. But it is *not* true that $[X,Y]=0$, since this doesn't hold in general for Lie algebras.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your answer, but can you give little more about free Lie algebra, that we can construct it.

Comment: @MANI Are the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020200/examples-of-free-lie-algebra) enough for you?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanku sir. I got my answer.

Comment: @MANI I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Did you mean a Lie algebra is unlikely to be a universal enveloping algebra instead of "it almost never happens that a universal enveloping algebra can also be a Lie algebra"? Because universal enveloping algebras are always Lie algebras under the usual bracket.

Comment: @justanothermathstudent I was talking about the usual product in a universal enveloping algebra, inherited from the tensor algebra, which makes it an associative algebra.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay. Another question: How exactly do we make the statement: "minimal possible amount of relations among its elements" rigorous?

Comment: Given a set $F$, if $\mathfrak f$ is the free Lie algebra on $F$ and if $\mathfrak g$ is a Lie algebra such that $F\subset\mathfrak g$, then there is a surjective Lie algebra homomorphism from $\mathfrak f$ onto $\mathfrak g$. In other, less precise, words, all relations whiach are valied on $\mathfrak f$ are also valid on $\mathfrak g$.